# App crashed on startup for an unknown reason

Tags: java, android, xml

There is a button in "MainActivity.java" which has an button with a onClick command of goToLoginPage and I have a second activity named "LoginScreen.java" and and in the UI, when I click the button, the application crashes.

### MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public void goToLoginActivity (View view){

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

## activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_bootiful"
        android:contentDescription = "@string/background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.62"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/divider"
        android:contentDescription="@string/divider_image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logInButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_dark"
        android:fontFamily="@font/staatliches"
        android:onClick="goToLoginActivity"
        android:text="@string/login_st"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.526"
        tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/light_button"
        android:backgroundTint="#00FF0000"
        android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
        android:fontFamily="@font/staatliches"
        android:includeFontPadding="true"
        android:text='@string/signup_str'
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.747" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_text"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text='@string/welcome'
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.231" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## LoginScreen.java

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class LoginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);
    }
}
```

## activity_login_screen.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginScreen">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_plain" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.165" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/field_bg"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_username_field"
        android:drawablePadding="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#9A9A9A"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@null"
        app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.424"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:background="@drawable/field_bg"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_password_field"
        android:drawablePadding="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@null"
        app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.532"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logInButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_dark"
        android:fontFamily="@font/staatliches"
        android:text="@string/login_st"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.699"
        tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Error Log

```
2022-10-06 16:32:52.589 4551-4551/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 4551
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.LoginScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.myapplication.LoginScreen.onCreate(LoginScreen.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080059
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:257)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:137)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:66)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:64)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:86)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:73)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:206)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:125)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1569)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.example.myapplication.LoginScreen.onCreate(LoginScreen.java:12) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
2022-10-06 16:33:01.959 4551-4551/com.example.myapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4551 SIG: 9
```

### (edit) AppManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginScreen"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## SOLVED

you need to make sure that the images you use are in the correct drawable folder other than the drawable-v24 folder

Comment: where and how you call goToLoginActivity() Method ?

Comment: in the main activity in line 11

Comment: Its looks like there is some problem with your image view in loginScreen.xml, check this line  app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_plain", is bg_plain in the drawable folder, or in drawable(v24) something, try with some other image, your log cat says, resource not found exception,

Comment: Real exception is `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080059`. Seems like you're using an image that doesn't exist in the right folder

Comment: yes, bg_plain is in the drawable folder

Comment: no wait, sorry the bg_plain was in the drawable_v24 folder. you need to check it in the files.